# What is the blur/translucency of the Tab Bar iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Trying to create a view that blends in seemlessly with the tab bar but in order to do that i need to find out the blur effect on the tab bar

Comment: What settings have you tried?

Comment: `UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
    blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
    UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
     visualEffectView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:49.0f/255.0f green:49.0f/255.0f blue:61.0f/255.0f alpha:0.6f];
    visualEffectView.alpha = 1;`